# Cannot render the panelGrid

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the primefaces form with commandbutton that popup the dialog form. In which I have the two panelGrid with same condition rendering. One is invisible but not another which contain the commandbutton that will update two panelGrid with rendering. I don't know why? Please help. I just guest whether panelGrid cannot be rendering real time by command button?

```
<p:panelGrid rendered="#{dtWebVoEsstv1s2.academicQuali.size()>0}"
             id="panelGrid1s4a5"
             styleClass="ui-edb-noneborder-grid">
    <p:row>
        <p:column><p:commandButton value="verify"
                                   action="approveProfileQualifications"
                                   update="@this, @parent, @([id$=panelGrid1s4a3b1]), @([id$=panelGrid1s4a4]),@([id$=panelGrid1s4a5]), @([id$=customMessage1s4])" />
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
    <!--This cannot be invisible of rendering-->
</p:panelGrid>

<p:panelGrid columns="1" id="panelGrid1s4a3b1" style="border: 1px solid #8c4eea;" >

    <ui:repeat  styleClass="ui-edb-td-wrap-table ui-edb-header-style"
                var="academicQualiDetail" value="#{dtWebVoEsstv1s2.academicQuali}"
                rendered="#{dtWebVoEsstv1s2.academicQuali.size()>0}">
        <!--this can be invisible after rendering by commandbutton click-->
```

Comment: When page loaded at that time if this `rendered="#{dtWebVoEsstv1s2.academicQuali.size()>0}"` condition false then PanelGrid is not in view so by doing this above condition true by some action, view will not able to render PanelGrid .

Comment: After communication with my friend, he said if the popup dialog is within form, then render  popup dialog may have problems. On the other hand, it popup dialog has form id within, the render of panelGrid will work. Is it true??

Comment: First thing is right when popup window have its own form.According to HTML nested form is wrong approach so JSF follow same.

Comment: On the other hand, ui-repeater is working for rendering but panelGrid not for real time commandbutton click. is it true in my original case??

Comment: You already added a condition here `rendered="#{dtWebVoEsstv1s2.academicQuali.size()>0}"` When page loading first time when condition false this component is not in your view so update will not work better use another component to put this Panel

Comment: Sorry. Let me mention better. When page loading first time, the condition is true and then it will show. When I click the commandButton, it will call spring webflow function which will call controller. Then the condition is false after back to webflow in which i will render the form:panelGridxxx. But it is still there and cannot be invisible.

Comment: Actually it is on popup dialog with below line on the first page.

Comment: <ui:define name="popupDialogContent">
  <h:form id="formDialogDetail" rendered="true" >
   <ui:include src="popup-teacher-detail.xhtml"/>
  </h:form> </ui:define>

Comment: The popup dialog within the form ID of "formDialogDetail".

Comment: Today all items on popup dialog cannot refresh after button click on this popup dialog. Any hints????

Comment: Better add some minimal running code so i can test it

Comment: When I put below update in commandButton, it has exception below:

Comment: Cannot find component with expression "formDialogDetail:teacherAccordDetail:panelGrid1s5a5" referenced from "formDialogDetail:teacherAccordDetail:cmdVerify1s5a2".

Comment: update=" formDialogDetail:teacherAccordDetail:panelGrid1s5a5 ,formDialogDetail:teacherAccordDetail:panelGrid1s5a6 "